# Assign an integer value to a string in C

Tags: c

I have a small problem assigning a string variable in C. Let's say we have `char string[100]` and I want to assign a string with an integer to this variable like in here.

What I tried was..

```
strcpy(string, "The tile in %d,%d is occupied: ", row, col);
```

But I get an error

> Unresolved externals symbol message.

Is there any other way that I could do it?

Comment: Ops sorry I added this quote wrongly. Removed from the question!

Comment: Is `string` accessible from the scope of this `strcpy` call?

Comment: Is the signature of `strcpy` correct? Isn't it `strcpy ( char * destination, const char * source )`

Comment: You provided 4 arguments to `strcpy` which only takes 2. Please see @selbie answer.

Comment: Welcome to SO. As soon as possible, please read the documentation on how to ask a question. This isn't an example. nb: there are problems with your line of code as others are saying, but that error message isn't coming from it, so you have other problems. In fact I doubt that's the exact error message. Again, the docs on how to write a question will be helpful to you.

Comment: ... and please read the docs for the functions you are using.

Comment: I know that strcpy only allows 2 arguments that is why I came here and asked how to apply 4 or if there is any other function..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 char string[100];
 sprintf(string, "The tile in %d,%d is occupied: ", row, col);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've got to understand is that a construct like `"The tile in %d,%d is occupied: ", row, col` is not some "magic" construct of the C language that always applies with strings. The reason for why you might think that, is that most beginners guides and books don't care to mention, what a line like `printf("You name is %s", name)` actually does.

It's not magic done by the C language, it's the how *`printf`*  (and whole `print`, `scanf` family of function) were design in the first place.

In C a string `"Your name is Mike"` and `"Your name is %"` are just two strings (a series of characters terminated with `\0`), the second one is no more special than the first one from the C perspective. The C language has also a special feature (some call it ellipses) that allow you to pass an undefined amount of arguments.

Take a look at this:

```
void foo(int a, int b);
```

With this declaration, there is only one way to call `foo`: with too arguments. If however `foo` would be declared as

```
void foo(int a, int b, ...);
```

then you can call foo so:

```
struct something k;
foo(1,2);
foo(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
foo(2, 3, "This is a string", k, &k);
```

Using `va_list` (Variable Argument Lists) `foo` can access the rest of the parameters passed to it that come **after** the last named arguments, in this case `b`.

`printf` is a function that allows this flexibility, you can call `printf` with many arguments (always at least one).

```
// man 3 printf
#include <stdio.h>

int printf(const char *format, ...);
int fprintf(FILE *stream, const char *format, ...);
int dprintf(int fd, const char *format, ...);
int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
int snprintf(char *str, size_t size, const char *format, ...);
```

As you can see, all these function are declared that way. The basic way that `printf` work, is that it reads the first argument and parses it. When it encounters a substring like `%d` it knows that the user has passed an integer. It retrieves the integer using `va_list` and prints the value of the integer instead of `%d`. Then in continues until it reaches the end of the *format*-String, always replacing the `%`s with values retrieved using `va_list`.

`strcpy` is declared as `char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);`, it doesn't use the "ellipse trick" as `printf` does, so your line is wrong and the compiler complains about it.

There are other function that use similar strategies as `printf`, but the vast majority of function accepting strings do not implement this "trick". For those cases you can use `sprintf`.